# Javascript - I can't make the "this" keyword on my html

Tags: javascript, html, this

This is currently my simplified code and it's not working. What I would like to do is to have two input(id's nono1 and nono2) calling the same function(nonoto). I cant use document.getElementById() because they different ID's.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function nonoto()
    {
         alert(document.getElementById(this.id).value);
    }
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: How do you use `nonoto` function?

Comment: uh, `document.getElementById(….id)` is pretty much the identity function (assuming that `…` is already an element, it's in the DOM, and there are no duplicate ids). In your case, use just `this.value`.

Comment: this is nonoto() now. I calls getMonthNum() which returns the numeric equivalent of the months of the year.
nonoto will called from two different id textboxes.
`var hnino;
 function nonoto()
 {
  hnino = document.getElementById("nono").value;
  alert(getMonthNum());
 }
 
 function getMonthNum()
 {
  
  var mon = /[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+/.exec(hnino);
  var month = ["january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"];
  var i = 0;
  
  do {
  var n = month[i].search(mon);
  i++;
  }
  while (n != 0 && i < 12);
  return i;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `nonoto` function, pass current input element object as `this`:

```
<input id="one" onchange="nonoto(this)" >
```

and function will become:

```
function nonoto(obj)
{
     alert(obj.value);
}
```

So the function doesn't have to know any ids to get element value.

Comment: Oh, right. I haven't thought of that. Thanks a lot. I still yet to deeply understand the use of "this".

Comment: Yes, it's tricky. `nonoto` is a global function, if you invoke global function just like `nonoto()` the context inside (`this`) will be global object `window`. However `on{something}` handlers are executed in context of current DOM element, so `this` points to element. You can pass this object in the function. Or you can invoke the function in correct context like `onchange="nonoto.call(this)"` then it will be invoked in context of DOM element.

Comment: So is my code above, wrong? or it's just a matter of what's calling the function. I got that code from somewhere else and I didn't saw how it is called. I'm just new to all of this OOP so I don't kinda know everything. though I only understand some basic OOP.

Comment: It's very important how the function is called. Depending on it `this` will be `window` or DOM element, or whatever. I recommend to pass object explicitly as `nonoto(this)` and not to deal with `this` in function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it somehow.